# CLASSPATH and Manifest file

Tags: java, jar, classpath, manifest

I do not understand the rules of setting a classpath within a manifest of a jar file.

I seem to get it to work and then not get it to work. From the documentation I have read so far I only know you can't use wildcards

Could someone please post a link on how to set the classpath within a jar file

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normally you generate manifest files by using build tools like Maven or Gradle.

If you want to do it manually you have to use following form:

```
Class-Path: jar1-name jar2-name directory-name/jar3-name
```

If you want to read more about it please visit http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html

Answer (score 0):

This method is used while a jar you are using is in turn dependent on other jars. Here is the link : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html ... One of the places I have seen it being used is WebSphere MQ http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r1/topic/com.ibm.mq.doc/jm10330_.htm