# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException while executing a jar file

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, jar, classnotfoundexception

I'm trying to execute a jar file and get the error - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException . The program is in Scala language written in Intellij IDE using scala-sdk-2.13.0 and it was then converted to jar.

Inside the jar file, I could find my main class (mypgm.class) and the MANIFEST.MF inside META-INF points to mypgm. But still, I get this error. Can someone please let me know why this happens?

I even tried 'java -cp myjar1.jar mypgm' to run the jar. But the same error occurrs.

Comment: How did you build the JAR?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the class `main.scala.Mal_ip` can't be found. Make sure that the class is included in your jar file, or reachable via the [`Class-Path` directive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21169814/classpath-and-manifest-file) on the manifest file.